# Coordinated Scrolling Between Two TableViews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I've got two overlapping `UITableView`s with only vertical scrolling. I want specialized coordinated scrolling across the two tables. I took the front table (in the view layering) and set `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` and added a `scrollViewDidScroll()` method to the back one. The front table ignore all gestures, so any pan gesture/scrolling would trigger on the back table. As scrolling occurred my `scrollViewDidScroll()` method would get called and I would check the `contentOffset` and scroll (set `contentOffset`) on the other table view as needed. It worked great.

[image]

Until.... the design added buttons to the front table view. I can no longer use `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` because this ignores taps and buttons won't work. I need allow for taps, but not respond to pans(scrolling). I thought it would be fairly easily, but I'm either missing something simple or it's more complicated than I would expect.

I've tried:

- Disabling scrolling on the front table (pan gestures get ignored, but don't fall through to the back table)
- Overriding the pan gesture in the front table and applying the offset to the back table (momentum doesn't work properly)
- setting the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` from the back table on the front one (gesture recognizers can only belong to one view)
- sub-classing the front table and doing an `override` of `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` to return `false` for pan gestures (pan gestures don't fall through to the back table)
- sub-classing the front table and doing an `overrider` for `touchesBegan` (moved, ended, etc) and calling the methods on the back table (no effect)
- and a few other things

I'm stumped on this. Help appreciated.

Edit: The image is from a simplified bit of code for a proof of concept. The real code has the top/front table changes `contentOffset` table height dependent on what's visible in the bottom/back table.

Comment: So the question is really "allow the cells to be tapped but not scrolled"?

Comment: @matt - Yes... but while still allowing the pan gestures in the upper/front table to be handled by the back/bottom table. IE, the user should be able to "scroll" from anywhere on the screen (which is the size on the back/bottom table)

Comment: Why two tables? Why not one table with two sections?

Comment: @DBD - your use of "front" and "back" table view is confusing... Is there a reason you don't use a "top" and "bottom" table view, where both are enabled and you synch the scrolling between them?

Comment: @HangarRash A section header can sticky to the top until the next section comes along and then the next section will sticky to the top. That's great, but I need something significantly more complicated.

Comment: @DonMag top/front and bottom/back. The top table is both at the top of the screen and overlayed in front of the table below it from both the Y axis and the Z axis. I left a little transparency in the red (top/front) table to show the green table extends behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of two table views - **not overlapping** each other.

We'll use the same cell class for both "top" and "bottom" table views, just so we can confirm that we can tap the buttons in the cells in both tables.

```
class CommonCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier: String = "commonCell"
    
    // closure for button tap
    var gotTap: ((UITableViewCell) -> ())?
    
    var isTop: Bool = true { didSet {
        var cfg = btn.configuration
        cfg?.baseBackgroundColor = isTop ? .systemBlue : .systemRed
        btn.configuration = cfg
    }}
    
    var btn: UIButton!
    
    let theLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    var myString: String = "" {
        didSet {
            theLabel.text = myString + " Count: \(self.tapCount)"
        }
    }
    var tapCount: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            theLabel.text = myString + " Count: \(self.tapCount)"
        }
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        cfg.title = "Button"
        btn = UIButton(configuration: cfg)
        btn.addAction (
            UIAction { _ in
                self.tapCount += 1
                // call the closure so the controller can
                //  update the data source
                self.gotTap?(self)
            }, for: .touchUpInside
        )
        
        [theLabel, btn].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            btn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
    }
}


class SynchedTablesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let topTable: UITableView = UITableView()
    let bottomTable: UITableView = UITableView()

    let topHeight: CGFloat = 226.0
    
    var tapCounts: [[Int]] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tapCounts = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 25), count: 2)
        
        [topTable, bottomTable].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            topTable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            topTable.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            topTable.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            topTable.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: topHeight),
            
            bottomTable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topTable.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bottomTable.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bottomTable.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bottomTable.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])

        topTable.register(CommonCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CommonCell.identifier)
        bottomTable.register(CommonCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CommonCell.identifier)

        [topTable, bottomTable].forEach { v in
            v.dataSource = self
            v.delegate = self
        }
        
        // bottom table needs to be able to scroll up far enough
        //  to show bottom row of top table
        bottomTable.contentInset.bottom = topHeight
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tapCounts[section].count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CommonCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CommonCell
        if tableView == topTable {
            c.isTop = true
            c.myString = "Top Row: \(indexPath.row)"
            c.tapCount = tapCounts[0][indexPath.row]
            // closure for button tap
            c.gotTap = { [weak self] c in
                guard let self = self,
                      let cell = c as? CommonCell,
                      let iPath = self.topTable.indexPath(for: cell)
                else { return }
                self.tapCounts[0][iPath.row] = cell.tapCount
            }
            c.contentView.backgroundColor = .init(red: 1.0, green: 0.75, blue: 0.75, alpha: 1.0)
        } else {
            c.isTop = false
            c.myString = "Bottom Row: \(indexPath.row)"
            c.tapCount = tapCounts[1][indexPath.row]
            // closure for button tap
            c.gotTap = { [weak self] c in
                guard let self = self,
                      let cell = c as? CommonCell,
                      let iPath = self.bottomTable.indexPath(for: cell)
                else { return }
                self.tapCounts[1][iPath.row] = cell.tapCount
            }
            c.contentView.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.75, green: 1.0, blue: 0.75, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        return c
    }

    // track which table view to use for content offset when scrolling
    var activeTableView: UITableView!
    var inActiveTableView: UITableView!

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let tblView = scrollView as? UITableView {
            if tblView == topTable {
                activeTableView = topTable
                inActiveTableView = bottomTable
            } else {
                activeTableView = bottomTable
                inActiveTableView = topTable
            }
        }
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let tblView = scrollView as? UITableView {
            if tblView == activeTableView {
                inActiveTableView.contentOffset.y = tblView.contentOffset.y
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

[image]

And, animation capture (too big to post here): https://imgur.com/a/V1yqj70

Comment: Great and synchronized, but you aren't doing any scrolling from the top view. Users need to be able to scroll from both because the final implementation will look like it's a single element.

Comment: @DBD - hmm... guess I'm confused about your goal? If you run that code, you can scroll (synchronized) both tables from anywhere on the screen. And, you can confirm the buttons are active and "tappable" in both top and bottom table views. So I don't know what you mean by *"you aren't doing any scrolling from the top view"*?

Answer (score 0):

So, if u don't wanna allow users to touch and drag the TOP table to scroll, but still allow them to tap on the button.

Try using this:
[isScrollEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619395-isscrollenabled)

> The default value is true, which indicates that scrolling is enabled. Setting the value to false disables scrolling.
>
> When scrolling is disabled, the scroll view doesn’t accept touch events; it forwards them up the responder chain.

Comment: `isScollEnabled` does not work. With Apple's doc saying "the scroll view doesn’t accept touch events; it forwards them up the responder chain" but the back/bottom table does not get the events.

Comment: @DBD It won't accept the Dragging, but still allows child UI elements to receive Tapping. I just tested again, it worked properly.
Have u tried this method yet?

Comment: Several times. It allows taps (buttons) on the top table and does not allow scrolling. Despite what the docs seem to say, it does not allow the pan gesture to pass through to the view behind it

Comment: @DBD My method above solves your issue in this: "I need allow for taps, but not respond to pans(scrolling).". Did u solve this yet?